# COMO COMUNICAR 2 VLAN EN SONICWALL

Tags: vlan

Good day,

I would like your help since I have a NSA 5600 sonicwall and I create 2 vlans on the interface x0 X0:V2 with ip 10.0.0.2/24 and X0:V3 10.0.1.2/24, but at the moment I can place 2 computers, one in vla2. and the other one in vlan3 they take my ip by dhcp but when I test connectivity from the pc that I have in vlan3 that has the ip 10.0.1.218 it gives me a ping to the gateway 10.0.0.2 but to the ip that has the pc of vlan2 which is 10.0.0.213 does not respond to me, I try it the other way around from the other vlan and the same thing happens to me I get to the gateway but not to the pc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WVOD.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQ35z.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vL44o.png)

Comment: what's wrong with the subject? Why is it all uppercase and a language I don't understand?